# Can't use cordova plugin open-native-settings on ionic 6+ ( legacy dependencies )

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, settings, native

I'm trying to install this ionic plugin to open native settings on my **ionic 6** application:
https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings

But due to legacy dependencies it can't be installed, I also dont' want to use --legacy-peer-deps as the pipeline we are using to build the app would fail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEyiI.jpg

any way to get this plugin be installed normally?

Comment: Image which you uploaded is not clear. Please upload clear Image.